# Problem when building Wireshark on Windows (Error MSB8020)

Tags: build, wireshark

Hi I have an issue please. I'm trying to build wireshark on windows 10 and so I execute the x64 visual studio developer command line and try to generate build files with this command:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 ..\wireshark
```

and then I got this error:

```
error MSB8020: The build tools for v142 (platform toolset = 'v142') could not be found. To build using the v142 build tools, install the v142 build tools.
```

the problem with that is that I build with vs 2019 and it uses vs build tools 2017 ?

can u help me please for solving the problem ?

Comment: Did you closely follow all the build instructions from https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSetupWin32.html#ChWin32Build?  In particular, be sure to open the correct command prompt from the "Visual Studio 2019" folder and to run all commands from that command prompt.

Comment: please at any folder in visual studio 2019 I can find the command prompt ?

Comment: I mean the complete path ?

Comment: From the Windows Start Menu, you should be able to find the Visual Studio 2019 folder, and in it you should find the "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019" shortcut.

Comment: I just have tried to create build files with the command again but I got the same problem

Comment: You appear to have a problem with your build environment.  I'd suggest carefully reviewing the Wireshark build instructions to be sure you didn't miss anything.  Maybe also check your `$PATH` to be sure the VS 2019 paths are before any VS 2017 paths?  Maybe post your `$PATH` here as well?

Comment: And which version of `cmake` are you using and where did you get it from?

Comment: Another thing you can do is whenever you have any type of build failure, I find it's often a good idea to compare the [Wireshark buildbot output](https://buildbot.wireshark.org/wireshark-master/waterfall) against your own so you can see what versions of the various tools are installed and to compare any differences.  If the buildbot is successfully building Wireshark, then there's almost certainly something wrong with your own environment or something different enough to be causing a problem that hasn't been identified yet.

Comment: I am using the cmake version 3.20.2

Comment: and I am using the x64 native tools command prompt but it uses the vs build tools 2017 by default ? how to modify it to use the vs build tools 2019 ?

Comment: because the platform toolset = 'v142' is available only on visual studio 2019 not on visual studio build tools 2017 ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi  Christopher Maynard thank you again so much for your help and support.
I finaly resolve the problem by using this command

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -A x64  ../wireshark
```

unstead of using this command:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64  ../wireshark
```

and by installing doxygen and setting all the paths environment variables and installing other dependencies. finaly I generated the build files of wireshark.

Thank you again